# How to merge array using same id

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, array-merge

I have two arrays and I want to combine them together

1) first look like this:

```
[11] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [name] => test
    )
[12] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [name] => test1
    )
```

2) second array look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [offer_id] => 11
        [countries] => Array
            (
                [SA] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 682                           
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [offer_id] => 12
        [countries] => Array
            (
                [KW] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 414                           
                    )
            )
    )
```

I want this result. How is it possible can any one provide solution for same?

```
[11] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [name] => test
        [countries] => Array
            (
                [SA] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 682                           

                    )

            )

    )
[12] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [name] => test
        [countries] => Array
            (
                [KW] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 414                            
                    )
            )
    )
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: please update your question with formatted php array and also format your expected output array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array1 as &$arr1) {
    $offer_id = $arr1['id'];    // Search for this offer_id in array 2
    $match = array_filter($array2, function($v) use ($offer_id){
        return $v['offer_id'] == $offer_id;  // Return matching offer id
    });
   $arr1['countries'] = current($match)['countries']; // Assign matched country to array
}
```